# How to work with associaion ids like with dirty attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activemodel

I have some Model that has_many another models. And I want to do something before save, if structure of associated models changes. Something like this:

```
class Foo < AR:Base
  has_many :bars

  before_save :do_smth, :if => bar_ids_changed? # like ActiveModel:Dirty

  def do_smth
    ...
  end
end
```

What is the better way to implement this?

Comment: Here is an interesting [article](http://anti-pattern.com/2011/3/22/dirty-associations-with-activerecord) on a related topic. The goal is a bit different, but depending on what you're going to do and what information you need in your `do_smth` method I think you could as well leverage `:after_add` and `:after_remove` callbacks.